# Java Regex Syntax Error

Tags: java, regex

How do I search this regex: `"\s*Lol(.*?)\s*"` in Java? This won't work.

```
Pattern posts = Pattern.compile(""\s*Lol(.*?)\s*"");
```

Comment: what are you doing to do with the result?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape backslashes (and quotation marks too)

```
Pattern posts = Pattern.compile("\"\\s*Lol(.*?)\\s*\"");
```

Official java tutorial on [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)